# Sending dynamic php page with mailgun

Tags: php, mailgun

I am trying to send dynamic emails via the mailgun API in PHP but i'm not having any luck.

I can successfully send emails if i just send simple dynamic content. E.g.

```
$email = test@test.com;
$firstname = Tester;
$result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
'from'    => 'Support Team <hello@xyz.com>',
'to'      => $email,
'subject' => 'Welcome to XYZ.com',
'html'    => "<html>Dear $firstname, this is a test.</html>"
), array(

));
```

However i'd like to be able to pull content from a dynamic page E.g welcomeemail.php?userid=1. So i tried to use:

```
$html = file_get_contents(welcomeemail.php?userid=1
'html'   => $html
```

However I get the following error **"Warning: file_get_contents(welcomeemail.php?userid=1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.**

When I remove the ?userid=1, it works fine but obviously without the dynamic content.

Can you please provide any suggestions on how I can incorporate dynamic content into my emails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the full http path to welcomeemail.php. For an example file_get_contents('http://localhost/welcomeemail.php?userid=1'). When you don't put it like that the file_get_contents() looks for the file 'welcomeemail.php?userid=1' in the file system which is obviously doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you! I knew i must have been doing something stupid not to get this to work. :)